# Merging two insert queries with Transaction. However I need to grab the first insert's row ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database, querying

```
$db->query("INSERT into `users` (username, password, email)
    VALUES ('$username', '$hashpassword', '$email')");

$userid = mysqli_insert_id($db->link);

$db->query("INSERT into `users logins` (userid, token, ip)
    VALUES ('$userid', '$token', '$ip')");
```

The above is old code. The below is my new:

```
$db->query("BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT into `users` (username, password, email)
VALUES ('$username', '$hashpassword', '$email');

[here I need to get the row ID of the above insert]

INSERT into `users logins` (userid, token, ip)
VALUES ('$userid', '$token', '$ip')
COMMIT;");
```

How can I grab the first insert row ID and use it for the second insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **[`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)**

```
...

INSERT into `users logins` (userid, token, ip)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$token', '$ip')

...
```

or how about creating `Stored Procedure`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE Procedure InsertRecord
(
    IN _userName VARCHAR(50),
    IN _passWord VARCHAR(50),
    IN _email VARCHAR(50),  
    IN _token VARCHAR(50),
    IN _ip VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE Last_ID INT;

    INSERT into `users` (username, password, email)
    VALUES (_userName, _passWord, _email);

    SET Last_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT into `users logins` (userid, token, ip)
    VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), _token, _ip);

    SELECT Last_ID;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Awesome. However I forgot to mention I'm setting a cookie just after the query: setcookie("id", $userid, time()+941920000, "/"). where $userid would of been the row id. Is there anything I can do here?

Comment: thale a look at `mysql_insert_id()` [link here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html)

Comment: I was originally using mysqli_insert_id(), however, I need to pull the row ID of the first insert. Using it after the transaction will pull the second insert id.

Comment: @Chaplin how about `stored procedure`? then you can get `Last_ID`

Comment: Never heard of that. Will Google it. Do you have an example at all?